# Java Authentication against Active Directory, authentication mismatch?

Tags: java, active-directory, kerberos, gssapi

So I have some code which I'm testing to make sure it works nicely for authentication. It works fine against straight kerberos, so I figured there should only be some minor hiccups with AD. Unfortunately, I cannot get around a KrbException: KDC has no support for encryption type (14).

I know the error is an encryption type mismatch. But I can kinit just fine, it's only in the code that I hit an issue. I'm not setting anything, so I think it should be inheriting the same defaults as kinit, but that obviously isn't the case.

The code-

```
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "TEST.SQRRL.COM");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "172.16.101.128");
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "./conf/jaas.conf");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "true");

// "Client" references the JAAS configuration in the jaas.conf file.
LoginContext loginCtx = null;
loginCtx = new LoginContext("Server", new LoginCallbackHandler("test".toCharArray()));
loginCtx.login();
subject = loginCtx.getSubject();
```

and the jaas.conf

```
Server {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=false
storeKey=true
useTicketCache=true
principal="accumulo@test.SQRRL.COM";
};
```

And, the stack trace-

```
>>>KRBError:
     sTime is Tue Nov 27 18:16:36 EST 2012 1354058196000
     suSec is 257213
     error code is 14
     error Message is KDC has no support for encryption type
     realm is test.SQRRL.COM
     sname is krbtgt/test.SQRRL.COM
     msgType is 30
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: KDC has no support for encryption type (14)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:696)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:542)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at authenticators.KerberosAuthenticator.<init>(KerberosAuthenticator.java:37)
    at main.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:91)
    at main.PlugServer.run(PlugServer.java:22)
    at main.PlugServer.main(PlugServer.java:42)
Caused by: KrbException: KDC has no support for encryption type (14)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(KrbAsRep.java:66)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReq.getReply(KrbAsReq.java:446)
    at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.sendASRequest(Credentials.java:401)
    at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireTGT(Credentials.java:373)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:662)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(KDCRep.java:133)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.ASRep.init(ASRep.java:58)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.ASRep.<init>(ASRep.java:53)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(KrbAsRep.java:50)
    ... 19 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: KDC has no support for encryption type (14)
    at main.PlugServer.run(PlugServer.java:36)
    at main.PlugServer.main(PlugServer.java:42)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: KDC has no support for encryption type (14)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:696)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:542)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at authenticators.KerberosAuthenticator.<init>(KerberosAuthenticator.java:37)
    at main.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:91)
    at main.PlugServer.run(PlugServer.java:22)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: KrbException: KDC has no support for encryption type (14)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(KrbAsRep.java:66)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReq.getReply(KrbAsReq.java:446)
    at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.sendASRequest(Credentials.java:401)
    at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireTGT(Credentials.java:373)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:662)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(KDCRep.java:133)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.ASRep.init(ASRep.java:58)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.ASRep.<init>(ASRep.java:53)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(KrbAsRep.java:50)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, I got it past this stage. I can only guess that the DES support in active directory for Windows Server 2012 is broken, as I ended up tweaking my krb5.conf file and setting the two default ticket types and permitted types to just aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 and it worked for the one user. After enabling aes256 for other users in AD, it continued to work.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide an example of your krb5.conf?

Comment: No can do, this was over a decade ago

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the user's account and check the 'use kerberos DES encryption types' checkbox.

You'll need to login to your DS as an admin to do this of course.

Comment: I have checked those boxes and reset the user's password with no success. This is on Active directory on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Looking at [`init()` in KDCRep.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/krb5/internal/KDCRep.java.html#131), the only part that looks it could be throwing your error is:</s>

```
    150           if ((subDer.getTag() & 0x1F) == 0x00) {
    151               pvno = subDer.getData().getBigInteger().intValue();
    152               if (pvno != Krb5.PVNO) {
    153                   throw new KrbApErrException(Krb5.KRB_AP_ERR_BADVERSION);
    154               }
    155           } else {
    156               throw new Asn1Exception(Krb5.ASN1_BAD_ID);
    157           }
```

<s>It does seem a bit odd that the error's being printed as a `KrbException`, but it could work since [`KrbApErrException`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/krb5/internal/KrbApErrException.java.html) is a subclass of [`KrbException`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/krb5/KrbException.java.html).  `init()` can't throw any other subclasses of `KrbException`, though.</s>

Scratch that.  A better possibility is that it's one of the `Asn1Exception`s in there, since [the constructor in KrbAsRep.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/krb5/KrbAsRep.java.html#51) catches and rethrows those errors as `KrbException`s (with an appropriate `initCause` that would match up pretty well with the stack trace).

`"Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)"` leads me to believe it's throwing a `Asn1Exception(Krb5.ASN1_BAD_ID)`, [since `Krb5.ASN1_BAD_ID` has value 906](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/krb5/internal/Krb5.java.html#281). That's not overly helpful, since that seems to be the default error in `init()`.

See if you can generate the `DerValue` corresponding to your configuration and inspect it manually, seeing where `init()` would reject it, then step backward from there, looking at what part of your configuration created the erroneous bits.

---

Upon further inspection, the message `"KDC has no support for encryption type"` leads me to believe [`Krb5.KDC_ERR_ETYPE_NOSUPP`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/krb5/internal/Krb5.java.html#221) must have been used.  But, as that's [only used for the default instance of `Etype`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/krb5/internal/crypto/EType.java.html#101), that might not mean much.

Comment: The 'Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)' is  standard exception in the lower levels of the Kerberos GSSAPI implementation. It gets thrown for a lot of things, but there is proper error handling in the layers above it. I'm fairly confident there is some sort of encryption mismatch between the server and java client, from the message from the KDC. I guess what I'm stuck on is how to set encryption types differently in the java client. The system's config is fine, since kinit worked. It's the java setup that's off and I don't know how to fix it. (I think)

Comment: In my case the `906` error required to add `[libdefaults]   allow_weak_crypto = true` into the `krb5.conf` file. It isn't great idea in general, but there is no other choice if you upgraded java version to 17+